# TFS Checkout using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: tfs, jenkins-pipeline, vcs-checkout

I have a requirement of TFS workspace mapping or checkout using Jenkins pipeline. I have the below code but getting connection timeout issue.

```
stage ("Checkout"){
            node("Nodename"){
                ws("D:/Windows/Checkout/") {
                    echo ("Checking out source code")
                    checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', credentialsConfigurer: [$class: 'AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer'], projectPath: '$/ProjectName', serverUrl: 'CollectionURL', useOverwrite: true, useUpdate: true, workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}'])}}
                }
```

[image]

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: If this is truly your connection string, then this is your issue: `serverUrl: 'CollectionURL'`

Comment: May related to this issue : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.

We found the issue is with the proxy configuration in Jenkins plugins.

Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced Tab

Under this We have the **HTTP Proxy Configuration** configured with proxy details. Once we removed it, checkout is happening as expected.

Thanks,

Dinesh.

Comment: Since this issue was resolved, you could accept it as an answer.This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.